# Rancher: always deploying to new stack

Tags: docker, docker-compose, rancher

I'm setting up a job on Rancher. When I start a command to deploy image to rancher, everything works successfully but I meet only one problem: new image always is deployed to new stack.

I have set up docker-compose and rancher-compose to true tag name. Example:

```
 labels:
      io.rancher.container.pull_image: always
      io.rancher.scheduler.affinity:host_label: tag=sc-dev
```

Please tell me why.

Comment: Needs more information. The `rancher-compose` stack name is inferred from the current directory name unless you overwrite it with `-p`. Can you please post your full `docker-compose.yml`, `rancher-compose.yml`, and the `rancher-compose` command you are using?

Comment: @AndyShinn wow. that's true. I meet this problem because when migrating to new server, someone has changed stack name. But I don't know convention of stack name is based on current directory name. Thanks so much :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Posting the actual answer since I answered it in the comments.

The stack name comes from the actual directory name. So, if the directory name is changing between `rancher-compose up` commands then it can lead to duplicate stacks.

Try specifying the stack name with `rancher-compose -p <name> up`. This will make sure the same stack is used regardless of the underlying directory name.